# Is it possible to use tbl_uvregression() to generate a consolidated table of multiple univariate competing risk regression models

Tags: r

I was able to use the following code to create a table of multiple univariate cox regression models:

```
univ_death <- tbl_uvregression(
    df[covariates],
    method = coxph,
    y = Surv(df$time, df$death),
    exponentiate = TRUE) %>%
    bold_labels() %>% #bold labels
    bold_p(t=0.05) %>% #bold if p < 0.05
    add_global_p() %>% #add global p for multilevel 
    italicize_levels()
univ_death
```

However, when I tried to do something similar using competing risk regression from the tidycmprsk package, i got the following errors:

Code:

```
univ_death <- tbl_uvregression(
    df[covariates],
    method = crr,
    y = Surv(df$time, df$comp_death),
    exponentiate = TRUE) %>%
    bold_labels() %>% #bold 
    bold_p(t=0.05) %>% #bold if p < 0.05
    add_global_p() %>% #add global p for multilevel variables
    italicize_levels()
univ_death
```

There was an error constructing model `(function (x, ...)  {     UseMethod("crr") })(formula = Surv(df$time, df$comp_death) ~      Age, data = .)` See error below.
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `model = map(...)`.
Caused by error in `map()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error in `value[[3L]]()`:
! Error in `get_all_outcomes()`:
! The following outcomes were not found in `data`: 'df', 'time', 'comp_death'.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

Anyone able to help troubleshoot?